# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character. Python

Tags: python, unicode, syntax, syntax-error, quoting

Could somebody tell me which character is a non-ASCII character in the following:

> Columns(str) – comma-seperated list of values. Works only if format is tab or xls. For UnitprotKB, some possible columns are: id, entry name, length, organism. Some column names must be followed by a database name (i.e. ‘database(PDB)’). Again see uniprot website for more details. See also _valid_columns for the full list of column keyword.

Essentially I am  defining a class and trying to give it a comment to define how it works:

```
def test(self,uniprot_id):
    '''
    Same as the UniProt.search() method arguments:
    search(query, frmt='tab', columns=None, include=False, sort='score', compress=False, limit=None, offset=None, maxTrials=10)


    query (str) -- query must be a valid uniprot query. See http://www.uniprot.org/help/text-search, http://www.uniprot.org/help/query-fields See also example below
    frmt (str) -- a valid format amongst html, tab, xls, asta, gff, txt, xml, rdf, list, rss. If tab or xls, you can also provide the columns argument. (default is tab)
    include (bool) -- include isoform sequences when the frmt parameter is fasta. Include description when frmt is rdf.
    sort (str) -- by score by default. Set to None to bypass this behaviour
    compress (bool) -- gzip the results
    limit (int) -- Maximum number of results to retrieve.
    offset (int) -- Offset of the first result, typically used together with the limit parameter.
    maxTrials (int) -- this request is unstable, so we may want to try several time.
    Columns(str) -- comma-seperated list of values. Works only if format is tab or xls. For UnitprotKB, some possible columns are: id, entry name, length, organism. Some column names must be followed by a database name (i.e. ‘database(PDB)’). Again see uniprot website for more details. See also _valid_columns for the full list of column keyword. '

    '''        
    u = UniProt()
    uniprot_entry = u.search(uniprot_id)
    return uniprot_entry
```

Without the line 52, i.e. the one beginning with 'columns' in the quoted out comment block, this works as expected but as soon as I describe what 'columns' is I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /home/cw00137/Documents/Python/Identify_gene.py on line 52, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Does anybody know what is going on?

Comment: Did you try reading the error message?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, line 52 is the line within the quoted comment block that starts with 'columns'. Removal of the whole line results in functioning code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using 'fancy' curly quotes in that line:

```
>>> u'‘database(PDB)’'
u'\u2018database(PDB)\u2019'
```

That's a [U+2018 LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2018) at the start and [U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+2019) at the end.

Use ASCII quotes ([U+0027 APOSTROPHE](http://codepoints.net/U+0027) or [U+0022 QUOTATION MARK](http://codepoints.net/U+0022)) or declare an encoding other than ASCII for your source.

You are also using an [U+2013 EN DASH](http://codepoints.net/U+2013):

```
>>> u'Columns(str) –'
u'Columns(str) \u2013'
```

Replace that with a [U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS](http://codepoints.net/U+002D).

All three characters encode to UTF-8 with a leading E2 byte:

```
>>> u'\u2013 \u2018 \u2019'.encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\x93 \xe2\x80\x98 \xe2\x80\x99'
```

which you then see reflected in the `SyntaxError` exception message.

You may want to avoid using these characters in the first place. It could be that your OS is replacing these as you type, or you are using a word processor instead of a plain text editor to write your code and it is replacing these for you. You probably want to switch that feature off.

Answer (score 1):

Previously encountered the same problem and same error, python2 will default to using ASCII encoding.
You can try to declare the following comment in the py file's **first or second** line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```