# SyntaxError on filename when trying to read file?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use machine learning to predict students' future grade, but am stuck at the beginning.

Seems like `pandas.read_csv` cannot read psv file, I got:

```
df = pd.read_csv(‘training.psv’)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

How can I read psv file through python?

Comment: Your issue is wrongly trying to use `...` (backticks) instead of quotes ('...' or "...") around the filename. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the filetype (PSV). If has nothing specific to do with files, you would get the same error if you used backticks in a print statement. This is a simple typo.

Comment: ...in fact they were Unicode quotes `U+2018,9`, which are also illegal for quoting a string. You can see this with `[ '{:02x}'.format(ord(c)) for c in "‘training.psv’" ]` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214801/print-a-string-as-hex-bytes)

Comment: ...to which an existing duplicate question-and-answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26841280/202229)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the quotes symbol. You should either use ' or ".

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv('training.psv')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv("training.psv", sep = "|", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

That should work